# Graphics and Sounds for the Game

Tags: graphics, audio

I am new to android and game developing too.
I wanna try my luck in game development.

The only thing is struggling is Graphics and sounds.
I've played many games with awesome graphics like angry birds for example.

So, my question is how to design graphics like those and how do game developers get sounds for the games.

Can you suggest me any place for free sounds for commercial use

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably slightly off topic for stackoverflow (I think there's another board for game dev, not sure).

But that aside, my $0.02:

If you're doing game development and focused solely on the programming, then I would suggest finding a partner that can do some or all of the things you're not comfortable with doing yourself. Honestly, you could try making some graphics yourself in GIMP or Photoshop and using Audacity to make your own sound effects, but they probably won't be as polished as if you can find someone experienced with that to do it for you. You can also try to find free sounds/graphics on the internet, but if it's anything specialized you're trying to make, you probably won't find anything suited to what you're doing, at least not without much trepidation. Also, if you're really serious about making some games, and you want to get some assets of high quality, expect to pay a little money to get a graphic designer or sound engineer to make something nice for your project.

As far as where to find such a person. Well, this is where I get a little hazy, there's probably better places to look, but one which I'm aware of is this site:
http://www.moddb.com/jobs

You can post ads for people to work on various aspects of games, so you could find someone that specializes in the skills you're looking for. People on that site may do so for free, too.

Good luck!